# Django Querysets & dynamic string filtering

Tags: django

It seems that `__in` is only suitable for integers. I am trying to filter by strings.

I've tried this but it does not work.

```
    groups = ['foo', 'bar'] 
    args = []
    for group in groups:
        args.append(Q(name=group))
    group_ids = Group.objects.filter(*args)
```

What is the preferred way to dynamically filter a Django queryset using strings?

Comment: What makes you say `__in` is only suitable for integers? It works just fine for strings.

Comment: @Mark is correct. See my answer below if you need something other than an `exact` match (e.g. `iexact`, `contains`).

Comment: @Mark: My bad. You are right. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__in` can be used for strings as it translates to a SQL `IN` operation. Whether or not it is case-sensitive my depend on your table/column collation.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is doing an `and` of all those values, and I assume you want an `or`? Try:

```
query = Q(name=groups[0])
for group in groups[1:]:
    query |= Q(name=group)

group_ids = Group.objects.filter(query)
```